# i am trying to move a symbol inside of an array (emu8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
part1Maze  dw  179,002,205,205,205,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,205,205,205,191
```

so basically i have this array in assembly, and i am trying to write a code that essentially moves the 002 which is a smiley face, to the right based on an input (lets say 'd'), so it switches places whatever is next to it, and i am struggling with this as ive tried to point to switch the two elements inside the array using the conventional method and it's not working, any ideas?

this is what i tried

```
mov si,0
mov bx, maz1[si]
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si 
mov maz1[si], bx
```

Comment: If loading both into registers then storing to the opposite places didn't work, then you're doing it wrong.  But you didn't show a [mcve] of your attempt so that's all we can say.

Comment: i added the code i attempted

Comment: Ok, your code has one load and one store.  But you need two separate word elements to change value.  like `mov ax, [maz1]` / `mov dx, [maz1+2]` and then store them.

Comment: What you've tried still isn;t reproducible.  Array is labeled `part1Maze` but you are manipulating with `maz1`. You should also check if `maz1[si]` doesn't read or write outside of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> part1Maze  dw  179,002,205,205,205,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,205,205,205,191
> ```

Since the maze data is ASCII code, you could define the array as **bytes**

```
maz1 db 179, 002, 205, 205, ...

...

mov  si, 1           ; Offset to where the 002 smiley is
mov  ax, maz1[si]    ; Read 002 and its right neighbour
xchg al, ah          ; Switch
mov  maz1[si], ax    ; Store
```

If you insist on keeping it as **words**

```
maz1 dw 179, 002, 205, 205, ...

...

mov  si, 2           ; Offset to where the 002 smiley is
mov  ax, maz1[si]    ; Read 002
mov  dx, maz1[si+2]  ; Read its right neighbour
mov  maz1[si], dx    ; Store neighbour
mov  maz1[si+2], ax  ; Store 002
```

Comment: You probably need `mov ax, word ptr maz1[si]` to override the byte size associated with the "variable", if emu8086 is like MASM.  And BTW, on more modern x86, `rol word ptr  maz1[si], 8` would be good (e.g. [Bubble Sort int8_t in 19 bytes of x86-16 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list/149038#149038)).  Real 8086 doesn't have immediate-count rotates, and a barrel-shifter was new in 386, but emu8086 might let you use it.